# resolving a custom promise in Angular(2-4) - new or not

Tags: angular

I am a beginner in Angular2 programming. I am trying to write a function that returns a custom promise. It looks like this:

```
removeItem(item, removeFile: boolean = true): Promise <any> {
        // remove the item from the list
        let index = this.items.indexOf(item);
        if (index > -1) { this.items.splice(index, 1); }
       // now if removeFile is true, also physical remove the image
       if (removeFile) {
         // file.removeFile is basically cordova's file removeFile that returns a promise
         return file.removeFile(file.dataDirectory, item.photo[i]);
       } 
       else { // return my own promise so its consistent 
         return Promise.resolve(); //<---- *THIS*
       }

}
```

The question I have is the line commented as `*THIS*` at the bottom. Every example I have seen does a `var p = new Promise(resolve, reject)`  ([one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) example of many).

Questions:

1) Why do I need to do that? The method above seems to work. I read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711243/promise-resolve-vs-new-promiseresolve) that answers it for another promise framework, but I can't wrap my head around it. Can anyone parse it for me?

2) If I must do a `p = new Promise`, I don't want to wrap my entire functionality inside its function like the examples show. Can I just do a return p.resolve() and p.reject() where I need to so I don't add to nesting?

3) To dive a bit more into what @Maximus said:

> You need a new Promise whenever there's some async work you wish to
>   perform and then either resolve or reject the promise

Why can't I use the same approach as above (that is, use `Promise.resolve/reject)`? For example, lets say I force a custom promise on `file.removeFile` (I know this is bad, but I'm just trying to understand why I need a new promise for async work)

```
if (removeFile) {
         file.removeFile(file.dataDirectory, item.photo[i])
         .then ({success=>return (Promise.resolve(success);},
                {error=>return (Promise.reject(error);});
       }
```

Edit: To clarify, I know perfectly well I don't need to wrap removeFile with my own promise. This was just to give an example of wrapping an async job with my own promise and yet not using `new Promise`. **In other words, can I learn from an example of an async job that would require me to do a `new Promise` and where `Promise.resolve` would cause issues?**

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I need to do that? The method above seems to work.

You don't need it. You variant:

```
return Promise.resolve();
```

is absolutely fine. The code you used:

```
Promise.resolve(value)
```

is sort of an alias for

```
new Promise((resolve)=>{resolve(value)})
```

You need a `new Promise` whenever there's some async work you wish to perform and then either resolve or reject the promise. For example, resolve a promise  in 1 second using `setTimeout`:

```
new Promise((resolve)=>{setTimeout(()=>{resolve(value)}, 1000)})
```

**Edit:**

You don't need to use `Promise.resolve()` here:

```
 file.removeFile(file.dataDirectory, item.photo[i])
 .then ({success=>return (Promise.resolve(success);},
        {error=>return (Promise.reject(error);});
```

This is the same:

```
 file.removeFile(file.dataDirectory, item.photo[i])
```

Comment: Thanks Maximus. I edited my original question to add a further question on why I need a a new promise even for async work

Comment: @user1361529, you probably have to learn how promises work. I added details regarding your update to my answer.

Comment: @Maximus Would be great if you provided some link to understand how promises work

Comment: @Maximus - I think you misunderstood my edit. I know I don't need it and I can return the promise returned by file.removeFile. That is what I am doing in my original code. The reason I edited it was to question why a `new Promise` is required for async work as you stated.

Comment: how would you resolve a promise in 1 second without `new Promise()`?

Comment: `setTimeout(()=>{return Promise.resolve();},1000);` won't work? Is the problem here that it the parent function will return `undefined` till this triggers in 1 second?

Comment: Okay, I don't think I really get a complete gist of where `new Promise` is really needed (I don't fully understand your last comment), but I think that is a different question on its own. Given you answered my key question - that is, my first method was fine for what I am intending to do, I'll accept that answer. I might post a separate question detailing only item 3) later. Thanks.

Comment: try building a chain of promises each resolving within a second and you'll see why `new Promise` is needed