# Difference between Promise.resolve() and just resolve()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I wrote the code below:

```
function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(!fs.existsSync(path))
            return reject(new Error("data.json file does not exist"));
        else {
            console.log("File is actually found!");
            return Promise.resolve("File found");
        }
    })
}

readFile(path)
    .then(value => {
        console.log(value);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

**What happens:**
If the file exists, the console output is just `File is actually found!` If the file does not exist, it displays: `data.json file does not exist` along with the error stack.

**What I want:**
When the file does exist, I want `File found` to be displayed in addition to `File is actually found!`.  I found that this happens when I replace `return Promise.resolve("File found");` with just `resolve("File found");` or even `return resolve("File found");`.

**Question:**
What really is the difference between `resolve()` and `Promise.resolve()`?  Why does returning or not returning *not* make a difference (I guess it is because it is the last statement in the function).

Note: I use `existsSync()` because I want the process to be blocking until the file is actually read, because if the file is not read, then there is nothing to be done!  I understand promise might not be needed here, but I still use it because that is what I am trying to learn.

Thanks!

Edit: One more question - what actually should be rejected and resolved?  I mean, in the code above, I pass `new Error(...)` to `reject()` and a string to `resolve()` - is that alright?

Comment: Promise.resolve returns a promise resolved to the given value. resolve resolves the promise you call it in ... you would never need to use Promise.resolve like you are, since it won't resolve the promise you are calling it in - note: Promise.resolve is a method of Promise, resolve is just a convention ... you could do new `Promise((good, bad) =>  good(1));` ... and the promise is resolved

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711243/promise-resolve-vs-new-promiseresolve

Comment: @AnkurR - not really, at least in that question there is no forever pending Promise :p

Comment: @AnkurR, this is not about a promise constructor at all.

Comment: You are looking for difference between them and that question's answers clarifies same. Your usage is just different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.resolve` wraps an expression in a Promise. So `Promise.resolve("File found");` is `'File found'` wrapped in a Promise that resolves immediately.

Look at where the wrapped Promise is going in this code - you're returning it to the caller of the `new Promise` constructor. But the Promise constructor completely ignores a return value, if any. It's kind of like returning something when iterating in `forEach` - it just gets ignored.

In order to resolve a Promise constructed via the Promise constructor, you *must* call the first argument provided to the callback (which is conventionally named `resolve`, but may be named anything you want).

Also note that there's no need at all to wrap the rejection in `new Error` - if you just have a string message to send to the consumer, it's fine to reject with just a string.

```
function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(!fs.existsSync(path))
            reject("data.json file does not exist");
        else {
            console.log("File is actually found!");
            resolve("File found");
        }
    })
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise((fnToCallToResolveConstructedPromise, fnToCallToRejectConstructedPromise) => {
        if(!fs.existsSync(path))
            fnToCallToRejectConstructedPromise("data.json file does not exist");
        else {
            console.log("File is actually found!");
            fnToCallToResolveConstructedPromise("File found");
        }
    })
}
```

You *can* wrap it in an error object if it provides useful info for you, aside from the string describing the error, but otherwise, best to omit it, and just call `reject` with a string.

Comment: Could you please elaborate - _But the Promise constructor completely ignores a return value, if any_?  Isn't the whole purpose of a constructor just to construct _something_ and return it to its caller?  In other words, what should a Promise constructor do, if not ignore a return value?

Comment: Yes, the Promise constructor ignores its return value. The only way to communicate with the consumer of the Promise is to call the `resolve` and `reject` functions (the two parameters to the constructor callback). That is what you should do in the Promise constructor - always call either `resolve` or `reject` eventually, so that whatever is using the Promise can see when the Promise resolves or rejects.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  So, just to clarify, when I called `Promise.resolve()` was I doing something different than just `resolve()`?  I mean, yes, I wrapped an expression in a Promise with `Promise.resolve()`, but then why was that expression not printed later on (in `then()`'s callback)?

Comment: When you call `Promise.resolve`, you're wrapping an expression in a Promise, and then the wrapped Promise goes unused, because, like I said, the Promise constructor ignores its return value. The way to chain something inside the Promise constructor with something outside it is to call one of the parameters provided to the callback - anything else will not be connected with outside the callback, by default. `resolve()` resolves the constructed Promise. `Promise.resolve('foo')` creates *another* Promise which goes unused, so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ah, now I get it.  Perfect.  Thanks for your help!